# Javascript getter function from within function

Tags: javascript, function, getter, anonymous

I am trying to create my object through a function, but I am unable to figure out the syntax for the getter function.

```
var myObject = 
{
  0:123,

  get a()
  {
        return this[0];
  }
}


console.log("This works: " + myObject.a);


function test()
{
    this[0] = 123;

// error
    this.a = get function()
  {
  return this[0];
  };
}


var myTest = new test();

console.log(myTest.a);
```

Within the test function, the assignment of the get function throws a missing semicolon error and if I remove the keyword "function", it says that get is not defined.

How can I assign a getter function to the current object within my function?

Comment: I don't think the `var f = get function(){...}` syntax is correct, use `var f=get {...}` instead. Your function `test` fails to parse, while removing the `function()` makes it work

Comment: You get that error as that is not the correct syntax to use for [defining a getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var myObject = 
{
  0:123,

  get a()
  {
        return this[0];
  }
}


console.log("This works: " + myObject.a);


function test()
{
    this[0] = 123;

    Object.defineProperties(this, {"a": { get: function () { 
        return this[0]; 
    }}});   
}


var myTest = new test();

console.log(myTest.a);
```

Comment: Is there a shorthand version similar to what I was attempting to do or is this the only way?

Comment: I do not think so. You can only use the short way with an object literal.   This is as close as i can get, and in this case, you are not passing back 'this'.

function test() {
 
  return {  
     "0":123,
     get a() { 
      return this["0"];
     }   
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you :

```
      function test()
      {
          this[0] = 123;

          Object.defineProperty(this, "a", { get: function () { return this[0]; } });
      }
```